# How to set User-Agent in Python MozEmbed?

Tags: python, mozilla, google-plus

I have build a simple dedicated browser (like Prism) which I use for different sites. Sadly Google+ blocks all browsers, but four. So it blocks mine too.

How can I set the User-Agent in MozEmbed, so I can tell Goolge, I am using Firefox?

```
    mozembed = gtkmozembed.MozEmbed()
    mozembed.load_url("https://plus.google.com")
    mozembed.show()
```

Comment: One would need to set `general.useragent.override` preference but I don't know how you would do that with MozEmbed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, haven't tested it, because my Mozilla stuff is inherently broken atm.

One way to set it is to create custom settings file [prefs.js](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/A_Brief_Guide_to_Mozilla_Preferences) and set that directory as profile directory:

```
profdir = '~/.config/mozilla'
profile = 'foo'
mozembed.set_profile_path(profile_directory, profile)
```

Now, gtkmozembed should read preferences from `~/.config/mozilla/foo/prefs.js`. Example [custom user-agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_user_agent_string_reference) entry:

```
user_pref("general.useragent.override", 'foo');
```

Another option would be to overload the `gtkmozembed.*_stream` functions to inject custom `User-Agent` header using `urllib2`.

PS. Try out WebkitGTK+ and gobject-introspection. Mozilla and GTK+ is a bit broken since Gtk+-3.

Comment: What exact values do I have to set into vendor, verdorSub and vendorComment to be identified as Firefox?

Comment: @Witek OOPS! Turns out that support for `vendorSub` and `vendorComment` was removed a while ago. For `vendor`, look for example from here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_user_agent_string_reference

Comment: ..and you can also try whether `general.useragent.override` works ;)

Comment: It worked with general.useragent.override: "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1". And instead of editing prefs.js, I just opened the URL about:config. Now Google doesn't block me anymore :-D

Comment: @Witek: Heh, didn't know that about:config works in pygtkmozembed :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible Solution here:

http://www.mail-archive.com/pygtk@daa.com.au/msg18189.html

basically its about getting the Website Content with urllib where you can set an User Agent and then read this content with mozembed

```
    fd = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': USER_AGENT}))
    html = fd.read()
    fd.close()
    mozembed.open_stream(url, "text/html")
    mozembed.append_data(html, len(html))
    mozembed.close_stream()
```